# How do I install driver for the Linksys WUSB6300 in CentOS

Tags: centos

I want to install the WUSB6300 driver in CentOS. I found good information for Ubuntu here:

[driver for WUSB6300 in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520870/how-do-i-install-driver-for-the-linksys-wusb6300)

However that did not get me anywhere since the C code did not compile in CentOS. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: yOU are correct. I lost that one and open this as a replacement. Now you found that. Thanks for this. I will remove the other one and leave this.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cd rt18812au
make
make install
```